# How to add different "From Name" value in SendGrid SMTP "From Email" Other than given in SendGrid account

Tags: smtp, twilio, sendgrid

I am trying to pass different different "From Name" for all email sending from my SendGrid SMTP credentials. But its just showing same name which I have in my Sendgrid site account instead of setting the From Name I am setting in my code while sending emails.

What I need to do to achieve this? Like I can send different different From name from my that one SMTP credentials. For me, From Email can be remain same for all email I am sending through that SMTP credentials. But From Name should allow to be change randomly.

Looking for a way out to achieve this goal.

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?